# Replace dots, commas and hyphens in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-server-2012

I have a problem as mentioned in the title. I have a database with some parts and its codes like this:

```
ID | Part_name | Part_code
---+-----------+-----------
1  | ...       | 123.1-233
2  | ...       | 12.32,211
3  | ...       | 123-12,22
```

I want to execute a `SELECT` query which will return results without dots, commas and hyphens. I think it can be done with `REPLACE()` but I cannot make it work.

I tried:

```
select replace(Parts.Part_code, '.', '') 
from Parts;
```

and it works, but I cannot make it for multiple signs with any regex, it seems that SQL Server ignores square brackets because it didn't work with:

```
select replace(Parts.Part_code, '[\.]', '') 
from Parts;
```

Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove multiple characters with multiple replaces I'm afraid

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Part_code, ',', ''), '.', ''), '-', '') 
FROM Parts;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, very simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple replaces are necessary.  One way to do the replaces without running up against the nesting limit in SQL Server is to use `outer apply`:

```
select p3.Part_code
from parts p outer apply
     (select replace(p.Part_code, ',', '') as Part_code) p1 outer apply
     (select replace(p1.Part_code, '.', '') as Part_code) p2 outer apply
     (select replace(p2.Part_code, '-', '') as Part_code) p3 ;
```